# Using MacRuby to Test iPhone Application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ruby, unit-testing, macruby

I have an existing iPhone app, written in Objective-C, that I'd like to add some automated tests to. I've read this [article about testing with MacRuby](http://macruby.org/recipes/tdd-in-objective-c-with-macruby.html), which sounds great but it's aimed at testing desktop frameworks.

How can I add MacRuby tests to my iPhone app? The Ruby code doesn't recognize my Objective-C classes, and I don't know how to set it up to do that. Do I need to somehow point it at the compiled code or the headers?

Answer (score 0):

[rbiphonetest](http://drnicwilliams.com/2008/07/04/unit-testing-iphone-apps-with-ruby-rbiphonetest/) worked for me back in the iPhone OS 2 and 3.x days with regular ruby. It was fairly limited though. I haven't tried it with 4.x or macruby specifically.

Answer (score 0):

MacRuby doesn't run on iOS, nor do I see that happening any time soon. I have been working on a port of Bacon (a Ruby rspec clone) to the Nu language: https://github.com/alloy/NuBacon. I still have to do some cleaning and write a blog post about it, I'll see if I can spare some time today to do so.